# Angular Universal in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

I am developing an Angular4 application. The backend is a NodeJs/Express huge part. I want to improve the Seo of my application with Universal Angular but I have a problem that I do not know how to solve.

The whole backend is written in javascript. In the documentation and in famous examples (ng-seed/universal) it say is necessary to use Typescript ... I tried to port the application to Typescript but it is a real hell; Is a very large application and incompatibilities arise everywhere .... Does anyone have any solution?

Is it possible to port the 'decorator' NgModule to javascript?

Thank you all.

Comment: is there any reason why you want to use JavaScript rather than ts-node? It's much more convenient to use ts-node with angular universal and @angular/platform-server code for building Server Side Rendering. What incompabilities do you have? Javascript should work out of box in ts-node so it's quite interesting what issues you encounter.

Comment: The backend of my aplicattion was made with the "angular-fullstack" generator, All the gulp tasks, and webpack generators expects javascript files. I dont know if i can a way to port only some files to ts-node, or only some files extensions... don know. I only trying to find the easiest way